# Missing crashlytics reports for app crashes. When should Crashlytics.start() be called?

Tags: android, performance, crashlytics

I've recently started using Crashlytics to monitor my app performance, however, I've noticed several occasions where my app would crash, but no crash report was sent to my dashboard.

[This article](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/206230-can-i-move-crashlytics-start-this) says that it's *okay* to call Crashlytics.start() inside a Base activity class, but doesn't suggest it as a best practice.

I'm curious if *not* doing so would result in missing crash reports? I'd rather not make unnecessary calls if I don't have to. Currently I'm only calling Crashlytics.start() inside my app's launch activity specified by my androidmanifest.xml file.

I'm curious as to what happens when the user closes my app (by pressing the home button or launching a different activity) and the GC disposes of my activity while it's in the background. When the activity gets recreated and there is no call to Crashlytics.start(), will I be missing those crash reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to lose any crashes, **it is recommended to put the `start()` call as soon as possible**.

And because the `Application` class is the first class to be instanced when you start your application, its `onCreate()` method is exactly where you should initialize the library.

If you refuse to do so, you may lose crashes related to your main Activity's inflation, for example.